# How to provide default values for array parameters in spring MVC url mapping?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getUserScoreCardDetails", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody List<ScoreDetails> getUserScoreCardDetails(
@RequestParam(value = "playerIds", required = false) int[] playerIds) { 

}
```

I need to provide default values [1,2,3] for playerIds if playerIds is not available in request?

Answer (score 10):

You can set comma separated values inside defaultValue property in @RequestParam

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getUserScoreCardDetails", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody List<ScoreDetails> getUserScoreCardDetails(
@RequestParam(value = "playerIds", required = false, defaultValue="1,2,3") int[] playerIds) { 

}
```

Comment: I tried this. But if playerIds is missing in request, playerIds is treated as null.

Comment: shouldn't be, this is well tested. please re.check

Comment: add System.out.println(Arrays.toString(playerIds)); inside the controller method and check the result.

Comment: I verified the result. Its coming as null. Might be because of old spring version. I am using spring.3.0.0

Comment: If anyone wants to default to an empty array, `defaultValue=""` does the trick. Works with lists too.

Comment: using 'defaultValue' implies 'required = false', so the 'required' attribute can be omitted.

Comment: @SeanConnolly Did somebody get a fix for this? It is still coming out to be null : `@DefaultValue("0") @QueryParam("offset") final Integer offset`. offset is null if it is not presnt in the url as query param or has misisng value after assignment.

Comment: Please read the answers given, or post a new question if you think you have a novel topic. It's not helpful to others to have long conversations in comments. That said, 1) you're using `DefaultValue`, that's not what this solution suggests, and 2) you're using `QueryParam`, that's not what the original question is about.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your method, just check, if `playerIds` is `null` and if it is `null` then specify the default values there like this

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getUserScoreCardDetails", method =
RequestMethod.GET)

public @ResponseBody List<ScoreDetails> getUserScoreCardDetails(
@RequestParam(value = "playerIds", required = false) int[] playerIds) {
     if(playerIds==null){
         playerIds = {1,2,3};
     }
}
```

Comment: I did the same thing. Thought there should be some better approach

Comment: i have read about this, and this is the elegant way to solve this problem... Just do it that way.. @Dhakchianandan

Comment: what you did now?@Dhakchianandan

Comment: i went with the above approach